Why can’t I set the resolution to 1080i even though it is supported by the TV I’m connecting to via HDMI?
I have been using my TV as a monitor in my Windows 11 laptop, but recently noticed that the TV was only recieving 720p input.
When I went to Windows settings it didn't have any option with 1920 x 1080 or similar, the only available option were 1080 x 720 or lower.
The laptop in question is an HP Victus with a Nvidia RTX 3050 GPU, all the drivers are up to date. And the TV is a Panasonic TH-37PV600E, which I checked on the manual and it does support 1080i (not 1080p).
The TV works fine with 1080i resolution from my STB, from another laptop with a Nvidia MX-130 GPU, and from a Playstation 3.
I tried using CRU (custom resolution utility) but it didn't seem to work too, even though I didnt find a decent tutorial online on how to use it.
Any idea what might be going on?

I'm not sure anything supports 1080i anymore. everything has been 1080p for so long that I don't think windows every supported it. your TV supports 720p, but not 1080p. I'm pretty sure I've never seen a computer monitor that used 1080i, so its not really a surprise that your video card or windows won't support it. https://www.manualslib.com/manual/649205/Panasonic-Viera-Th-37pv600e.html?page=17#manual

And if it could work, many find interlaced display annoying for close work on a monitor due to alternate-line flickering. For a TV used at a meter or two, the lines blend.

@FrankThomas I assumed it would work since my GTX MX-130 handles interlaced fine,  but Nvidia allegedly removed support on the 2000 series...

@DrMoishePippik I was mainly going to use it to play videogames from my couch, but I felt a strange eye strain when using 720p, so I thought it was due to the low resolution. I used to play on my PS3 and never felt anything
